# Unable to read .msg messages from MimeMultipart

Tags: jakarta-mail

I have a Java class which reads email using the javamail API. the problem I'm facing is that when I send a mail containing a .msg attachement, my application is not able to read the attachment.

I'm using JDK 1.7

```java
if (Part.ATTACHMENT.equalsIgnoreCase(part.getDisposition())) {
    MyAttachments attachment = new MyAttachments();
    String fileName = part.getFileName();
    StringBuffer filePath = new StringBuffer();
    filePath.append(fileUploadPath);
    filePath.append(createdDate);
    File file = new File(filePath.toString());
    if (! file.exists()) {
        file.mkdirs();
    }
    String attachmentFilePath = filePath.toString();
    part.saveFile(attachmentFilePath);
}
```

When I see the saved file, it is corrupted (the size of file is different, the file extension is not shown).

Comment: What's the MIME type of the attachment?  How are you trying to read the attachment?  Since you're creating the file name in "filePath", you'll need to include an appropriate extension as part of the name.

Comment: @bill Shannon: The MIME type is multipart/mixed.

Comment: we did try with renaming the file but did not work and read is happening by the object of the class MimeBodyPart. Here is the code sample of that.`MimeBodyPart part = (MimeBodyPart) mp.getBodyPart(partCount);
MyAttachments attachment = new MyAttachments();
String fileName = part.getFileName();
StringBuffer filePath = new StringBuffer();
filePath.append(fileUploadPath);
filePath.append(createdDate);
filePath.append(prId);
File file = new File(filePath.toString());
String attachmentFilePath =filePath.toString()+DomainConstants.FORWARD_SLASH+fileName+".msg"; part.saveFile(attachmentFilePath);`

Comment: @BillShannon To be more precise,the mime type of the message is "message/rfc822"

Comment: The code above shows how you **write** the file, not how you **read** it.  If you're reading it with (for example) Outlook, try changing the filename extension to ".eml".  If that doesn't work, show me what the contents of the file look like, at least the first few lines.

Comment: @Bill Shannon , Thanks for your valuable and kindly reply. Changing the the attachment Hello.msg to Hello.eml is working fine now.  Again one stuff , could we retain the same file extension as Hello.msg ,else some time user will behave it as different file as "Hello.eml"  because it's extension is different .

Comment: The problem here is with Microsoft, who namend their binary coded Outlook/Exchange Message files ".msg". So whenever you talk to Exchange/Outlook guys, there will be confusion on this. My advice: Stick with .eml

Comment: @Jan Do you have any official links or official documentation where this is problem has been highlighted that .msg has this kind of problem.? Please share if you have any.

Comment: Nothing of that kind. Just been doing email programming for a long time now - and .msg in conjunction with Outlook/Exchange almost always lead to trouble.

Comment: You can find out more about .msg files [here](http://windowsitpro.com/outlook/q-what-outlook-saved-mail-msg-file-format-and-what-security-problems-come-its-use).  These files are definitely not internet standard MIME format files, which is what JavaMail understands.

Comment: Thank you Jan and Bill for the information, it did work however we still are facing the same issue when the content type is application/ms-tnef; In this case we are not even getting the file name, it just appears as null. To solve this we tried sending mails from Plain text format to HTML format it did not work, the result is same. One more interesting point is this behavior is not consistent. Two users having the same client (outlook 2013) are getting different results. In one client we are getting the file name and in another client we are not. Any particular reason for this?

Comment: MS has given some information about this in https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/290809, however the question is sill same, 1. why two outlook clients having the same version are behaving differently?  2. How to overcome this problem?